# $_POST value returns blank/empty

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I do have a form where the user can retrieve the data depending on the dates selected. Here's what I have:

```
<form class="form" method="post">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-5">
            <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm" for="From">From</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fromDate" name="fromDate" value="<?php echo (new DateTime('first day of this month'))->format('Y-m-d');?>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2 col-5">
            <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm" for="To">To</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="toDate" name="toDate" value="<?php echo (new DateTime('today'))->format('Y-m-d');?>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-1 col-2">
            <label class="col-form-label col-form-label-sm text-white" for="Search">Search</label>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="getResult()">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div id="data_result"></div>
```

On the same page, I have a script below:

```
<script>
    function getResult(){
    var fm = $('#fromDate').val();
    var to = $('#toDate').val();

    $.ajax({
         method: 'POST',
         url: 'chart-data/card-sales.php',
         data: { fm:fm, to:to },
         success: function(data) {
              $('#data_result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And finally, my `chart-data/card-sales.php` file:

```
    <?php
    // db settings
    $hostname = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = 'password';
    $database = 'accounts';
    
    // db connection
    $con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
    
    $fm = '';
    $to = '';
    
    if(isset($_POST['fromDate'],$_POST['toDate']))
    {
        $date1 = strtr($_POST['fromDate'], '/', '-');
        $fm = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date1));
        
        $date2 = strtr($_POST['toDate'], '/', '-');
        $to = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date2));
    } else {
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
    
   
    echo'<div id="data_result">
            <h6> 
                <span class="text-danger">'.$fm.'</span> to 
                <span class="text-danger">'.$to.'</span>
            </h6>';
            
            $sql="SELECT * FROM sales WHERE date >='$fm' and date <= '$to'";
            foreach ($con->query($sql) as $row) {
                echo'//table contents';
            };
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

The thing is, `$fm` and `$to` returns an empty value (1970-01-01) that is why I couldn't get the proper data I need while the `var_dump($_POST);` returns `array(2) { ["fm"]=> string(10) "2021-01-01" ["to"]=> string(10) "2021-01-26" }`. So I think the main problem here is that I cannot get the input value from my form. Why is that so?

Comment: The indexes in $_POST are `fm` and `to` (because you _specified_ those parameter names in your `data` value of the AJAX call), yet you are trying to access `$_POST['fromDate']` and `$_POST['toDate']`.

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: sql injection `WHERE date >='$fm'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using the correct indexes on $_POST.

You should use the same indexes that you sent in the ajax: `fm` and `to`.

Change this:

```
if(isset($_POST['fromDate'],$_POST['toDate']))
{
    $date1 = strtr($_POST['fromDate'], '/', '-');
    $fm = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date1));
    
    $date2 = strtr($_POST['toDate'], '/', '-');
    $to = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date2));
} else {
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

To this:

```
if(isset($_POST['fm'], $_POST['to']))
    {
        $date1 = strtr($_POST['fm'], '/', '-');
        $fm = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date1));
        
        $date2 = strtr($_POST['to'], '/', '-');
        $to = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date2));
    } else {
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
```

P.S: Yo should take a look about SQL injection and prepared queries as @Strawberry suggested.

I encourage you to change to an object-oriented aproach using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.pdo.php)

Comment: All this time, I thought I have to use the input name to retrieve the value. And yes, I have another version where I used PDO. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As you send in your ajax call, data: {fm: fm, to: to} this is what to use.
Try to change:

```
if (isset ($_POST['fromDate'], $_POST['toDate']))
{
    $date1 = strtr($_POST['fromDate'], '/', '-');
...
    $date2 = strtr($_POST['toDate'], '/', '-');
...
}
```

by

```
if (isset ($_POST['fm'], $_POST['to']))
{
    $date1 = strtr($_POST['fm'], '/', '-');
...
    $date2 = strtr($_POST['to'], '/', '-');
...
}
```

Comment: Haven't thought of that. It solved my problem. Thank you.